# php format date() to 24 hour format when inserting

Tags: php

am using

```
$datetime = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

it is inserting into my database but - three hours.
for example my time is 09:30 pm it will insert 18:30.
Please help.Regards

Comment: you are probably in a timezone which is `UTC +3` , and while inserting into the database, it is stored in UTC

Comment: you should add `$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` if you want the time to be in UTC or it your default timezone offset will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
    g   12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros (1 through 12)
    G   24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros (0 through 23)
    h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    (01 through 12)
    H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    (00 through 23)

    <?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'');?> // 24 Hours format
```

Below are TimeZone converter,

```
                PDT: America/Los_Angeles: <?php echo DatePNForServerTimeZone('D d M Y H:i:s A', 'America/Los_Angeles'); ?>                  

                EST: America/New_York: <?php echo DatePNForServerTimeZone('D d M Y H:i:s A', 'America/New_York');   ?>                  

                IST : Asia/Kolkata: <?php echo DatePNForServerTimeZone('D d M Y H:i:s A', 'Asia/Kolkata');  ?>                  

                <?php 
                    function DatePNForServerTimeZone($format='Y-m-d H:i:s', $Zone ='America/Los_Angeles'){

                        $utc = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
                        $new = new DateTimeZone($Zone);
                        $date = new DateTime(gmdate("m/d/Y H:i:s"), $utc);
                        $date->setTimezone($new);
                        return $date->format($format);

                    }

                ?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

use date_default_timezone_set like following

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)